# How to view old messages in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In odoo 8 there was a menu called archives where read messages appear, but in odoo 9 there is not such a thing. 
Does any one know how to view the read messages or make it possible using filter. As well send avatar is also not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research by my self. and i found a way to keep the messages in the inbox folder but hidden. here is my method.

I create an active field and custom filter in mail.message and overwrite set_message_done method as below.

```
@api.multi
def set_message_done(self, partner_ids=None):
    """ Remove the needaction from messages for the current partner. """
    partner_id = self.env.user.partner_id
    self.active = False
    messages = self.filtered(lambda msg: partner_id in msg.needaction_partner_ids)
    if not len(messages):
        return
    #messages.sudo().write({'needaction_partner_ids': [(3, partner_id.id)]})
    # notifies changes in messages through the bus.  To minimize the number of
    # notifications, we need to group the messages depending on their channel_ids
    groups = []
    current_channel_ids = messages[0].channel_ids
    current_group = []
    for record in messages:
        if record.channel_ids == current_channel_ids:
            current_group.append(record.id)
        else:
            groups.append((current_group, current_channel_ids))
            current_group = [record.id]
            current_channel_ids = record.channel_ids

    groups.append((current_group, current_channel_ids))
    current_group = [record.id]
    current_channel_ids = record.channel_ids

    for (msg_ids, channel_ids) in groups:
        notification = {'type': 'mark_as_read', 'message_ids': msg_ids, 'channel_ids': [c.id for c in channel_ids]}
        self.env['bus.bus'].sendone((self._cr.dbname, 'res.partner', partner_id.id), notification)
```

summary: I comment the write line and add self.active = false. so the method will hide the message instead of removing it. but still there was message unread count bubble.

then i overwrite the get_needaction_count in res.partner and add a simple logic.

```
@api.model
def get_needaction_count(self):
    """ compute the number of needaction of the current user """
    if self.env.user.partner_id:
        id = []
        active_msg = self.env['mail.message'].search([('active','=',True)])
        for x in active_msg:
            for rec in x.partner_ids:
                id += [rec.id]
        if self.env.user.partner_id in id:
            return len(active_msg)
    _logger.error('Call to needaction_count without partner_id')
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For viewing the messages in ODOO9 Go through these steps:

1. Activate the  the **Developer mode** .
2. Go to Setting-> Technical->Email->[Message](http://prntscr.com/awza6t) .

In the **message menu** you can find the list of all message .

Hope this may help you .

Comment: So this is for admin how should the employee see their old messages

Comment: not displaying. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5gv2xr9v4x7q2o6/AACO6agOs-dQZkWb5BrgRYcCa?dl=0

Comment: it's working at my end, please  ensure that record is there or not in the database

Comment: Yes they are still there. if you check i attached two image one is email/messages you can see that emails are still in there. when i click mark as read from inbox it wont came back

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the archive function/field is not anymore present in odoo v9. In Odoo 8 the field is called 'to_read'. Somehow the read messages are getting unlinked in V9, but I don't know how. Others do not know either:
https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1/question/odoo-9-archives-messages-92788

Answer (score 0):

Finally there is one module that brings the Archive back:
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/mail_archives/
but not for free!

note:
there are others new modules from It-Projects LLC to improve the mail/messaging in odoo 9.